# I have a problem with IDLE Mode on Huawei devices when screen is turned off

Tags: android, huawei-developers

I am developing an application that monitors the physical activity of user (ON_BICYCLE, RUNNING, WALKING, IN_VEHICLE, STILL, ON_FOOT).

.
So far I've tested the app on Samsung (android ver 7-10), Moto (android ver 7-10) and  xiaomy phones (android version 8) and it worked Ok even when the screen turns off (in the background).

I recently started testing on Huawei Y6(2018)  (emui 8.0.0) and there is a problem when the phone turns off screen and is left without a WIFI network.

If the screen is OFF and  phone have WIFI network - application works Ok.

If the screen is ON and  phone is without WIFI network - works Ok.

But if the screen is off and the phone loses the WIFI network, application is freezes, no ActivityTransitionUpdates and no onLocationChanged. After that if screen is turned ON or phone again have WIFI network, everything is Ok.

On the phone I set 'Launch' to Manual and IgnoreBatteryOptimisation to Allow.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: If the screen is OFF and the phone(Samsung, Moto, Xiaomi) is without WIFI network, can the application work OK?

Answer (score 0):

If your users are using Huawei phones, you can prompt users to add protected applications to your settings to further reduce the probability of service killing. Go to **Settings** > **Battery** > **Battery Usage** > **Your App**, turn off **Management Automatically**, enable **Auto-launch**, **Secondary launch**, **Run in background**.

You can also integrate [Push Kit](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-push-clientdemo-android), make the notification to users, and show it as foreground.

Comment: Yes, all that is set on phone, but problem persist, as I mentioned, only when screen is turned off and phone is without WIFI network.

Comment: @RobertHadzi-Mehmedovic If the phone turns off the CPU(with no network), the app will be killed. I read [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock), are there any approach you can take (depending on the needs of your app)?  You could also use [Cloud Debugging](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddebug-realtimedebug?ha_source=hms1) to test your app on other mainstream Huawei devices to see if the problem persists.